# How to compose Actions in ReactiveSwift ("run the first enabled action from this list")

Tags: swift, reactive-swift

I have two `Action`s with the same input/output/error types, and I'd like to compose them into a single `Action` that runs whichever of the two is enabled (with an arbitrary tie-breaker if they both are).

Here's my first, failing, attempt:

```
let addOrRemove: Action<MyInput, MyOutput, APIRequestError> = Action(enabledIf: add.isEnabled.or(remove.isEnabled)) { input in
    if add.isEnabled.value {
        return add.apply(input)
    } else {
        return remove.apply(input)
    }
}
```

This fails because the inner `add.apply(input)` can't see that I checked `add.isEnabled`, so it wraps an additional `ActionError<>` layer around the error type. (This might be legit, as I'm not sure how thread-safe this approach would be, or might be a case of us knowing something the type system doesn't.) The corresponding type error is:

```
cannot convert return expression of type 'SignalProducer<MyOutput, ActionError<APIRequestError>>' to return type 'SignalProducer<MyOutput, APIRequestError>'
```

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github user [@ikesyo](https://github.com/ikesyo) provided the following answer on the [ReactiveSwift issue I opened to ask the same question](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/issues/366):

```
let producer: SignalProducer<MyOutput, ActionError<APIRequestError>>
if add.isEnabled.value {
    producer = add.apply(input)
} else {
    producer = remove.apply(input)
}
return producer.flatMapError { error in
    switch error {
    case .disabled: return .empty
    case let .producerFailed(inner): return SignalProducer(error: inner)
    }
}
```

If they show up here I'll happily change the accepted answer to theirs (credit where it belongs).

Warning: If I'm reading this answer correctly, it's not watertight. If `add` changes from enabled to disabled between the `apply()` and the `start()` of the wrapping `Action`, we'll get "success" (no values, but `.completed`) instead of the `.disabled` we should get. That's good enough for my use case, but YMMV.